# How to add more than one foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I link tables with more than just one foreign key?

For example I have a table named Member.

```
Member (Member ID, Member Name, Age, Address)
```

I have another table Member_Fees_Record.

```
Member_Fees_Record (Member ID, Member Name, Age, Address)
```

I want the fees record table to connect with member table, but as my member's table primary key is `Member ID` I can only make it a foreign key.

How can I connect `Member Name` to other table?

Comment: Read about normalization. You must not have the same data in different tables(data duplication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I connect Member Name to other table

Don't - leave `Member Name` in the member table.  There should not be any reason to have a `Member Name` field in the `Member_Fees_Record` table if you can join it back to `Member` through the ID:

```
Member (Member ID, Member_Name, Age, Address)

Member_Fees_Record (Member ID, Fee)
```

Example query:

```
SELECT m.MemberId, f.Fee, m.Member_Name, m.Address, m.Age
FROM Member m
INNER JOIN Member_Fees_Record mf ON m.MemberID = f.MemberID
```

Comment: @D Stanley How do I join it back to Member through ID ?? I am not getting it please post a link to a tutorial ?? Or give me some example? THanks

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple and orderly, fields like Member Name, Age, and Address should only exist in 1 table. You can use Member ID as the primary key of Member table and as a foreign key in Member_Fees_Record. I think the part you're missing is the "join" between the tables using SQL.

Example: select a.Member_Name,a.Age,b.Fee_Amount
from Member a, Member_Fees_Record b
where a.Member_ID = b.Member_ID
and a.Member_ID = 17;

Comment: I have an example above. In a nutshell, you join tables for the duration of a SQL query using a common field (in your case Member_ID). The tables and the data stay 'unjoined' outside of when your SQL statement is run (if that makes sense). There's also a more modern syntax that uses the key words 'INNER JOIN' as part of the SQL query. What I showed in example is old way of doing it.